# How to push from server to Google TV?

Tags: android, push-notification, push, long-polling, google-tv

I have an app that will always be running on the Google TV.  I would like for my server to be able to notify the Google TV when it has a new message.  I could do this by having the Google TV poll the server but I was looking for a better solution.

Comment: AFAIK, C2DM should work with Google TV.

Comment: There are no guaranteed delivery times.

Comment: True no guarantee, but generally quite quick.

Answer (score 4):

Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) is the preferred way.  http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/

Comment: "C2DM has been officially deprecated as of June 26, 2012" ... "Existing C2DM developers are encouraged to migrate to the new version of C2DM, called [Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM)](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html)" -- http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/

Answer (score 1):

If your server logic is running on Google App Engine, possibly you can use a channel  http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/overview.html  (yes, I know, this is a long shot in the dark).

Answer (score 0):

I would have used server side events, or web sockets, but then noticed on caniuse.com that it's not supported on the Android browser, just on chrome.   Which brings up an interesting point.  When trying to determine what is supported by the Google-TV browser, on 3.1 or 3.2 for instance, do we just use the Android browser support as reference or is there a source that provides us specific information concerning HTML5 and other support?